# Keeps asking to login Magento 2.3.4

Tags: checkout, login, customer-session, checkoutsession, customer-login

Not sure if this is a bug or if this is an actual issue which is going on. I have tried to read up on few informations and tried to follow the steps.
But I am not getting anywhere unfortunately.

The issue I am facing currently is the following 
If I tried to login to a customer from the admin area buy clicking login account it logs in without any issue.
But the name is not showing and also when I get to checkout and try to click proceeds to checkout it keeps asking to login

Please can anyone suggest the way around this problem

Comment: same issue facing